# BluebirdJS bind() in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bluebird

I'm having some weird behavior in a node.js AWS lambda function. In my local environment, I'm using bluebirdjs to handle my promises. I originally was "promisifying" the aws-sdk myself but later found this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/ and converted it to use the "promise versions" of the aws-sdk methods.

Basically, my problem comes in when I try to use the bind method of bluebird (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html) to pass data through the promise chain. This works on my local environment and in my tests. When I deploy to lambda, however, I always get an error saying "stack: 'TypeError: Cannot set property \'property\' of undefined\n" which seems to me like "this" in the promise.then() callback is not defined. Does anyone have any clue as to why .bind() would work on my local machine and not in AWS Lambda? I'm running the same version of node.

Here's what I'm doing

```
let s3getObjectPromise = s3.getObject({Bucket: bucket, Key: file}).promise();
s3getObjectPromise
    .bind({})
    .then((data) => {
        this.test = 'test';
        return parsePOICSV(data, type)
    })
    .then(function(recordsToUpdate) {
        let test = this.test; // THROWS ERROR
        // pass recordsToUpdate down the promise chain
        let searchRequests = elasticSearchService.constructQuery(recordsToUpdate);
        return elasticSearchService.search(searchRequests, recordsToUpdate);
    })
```

Comment: what does your `parsePOICSV` function look like?

Comment: @JoshBeam it just basically parses a csv file from S3 and returns a promise. It's not the problem though, I have tested it without that function and have tested the whole thing locally. It's something to do with it running in the lambda environment.